# Why is image uploader not working on chrome?

Tags: javascript

I have a button where you can upload an image and insert it in a  tag, it works on every browser but not on chrome. The first `reader.onloadend` is processed, I can log `image` and `image.src`.

```js
var inputUpload = document.getElementById('buttonUpload');

inputUpload.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = () => {
  //Initiate the JavaScript Image object.
  var image = new Image();

  image.src = reader.result;
  console.log('image.src');

  image.onloadend = function() { /* execution stops here */
    var height = this.height;
    var width = this.width;
    if (height > 150 || width > 150) {
      showAlert('Image dimensions must be within 150&times;150 pixels.');
    } else {
      // convert file to base64 String
      const base64String = reader.result.replace('data:', '').replace(/^.+,/, '');
      // display image
      valueImg = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
      updateImg(valueImg);
    };
  };
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```html
<button id="buttonUpload" type="button" class="d-inline btn-custom mx-0">
     Upload
</button>
```

When I select the image file, it stops at image.loadend but I get no errors in the console

Comment: Please don’t read large binary files into `data:` URI strings - it’s a huge waste of memory. We have `blob:` URIs which are much more faster and efficient, and can be used for practically anything, including video.

Comment: @Dai I need to store the image in mongodb and it's not possible with blob, do I have other options other than base64?

Comment: Your page's JavaScript does not have anything to do with MongoDB, but that's besides the point: you should not be storing files like that in MongoDB in the first place. **[MongoDB is not designed to store large binary objects](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/storing-large-objects-and-files/)** - instead you should store files in a proper large-binary storage system (e.g. some self-hosted S3-compatible server)